# Fixing a missing solder pad

Tags: soldering, pad

Shown below is the PCB of a panel controlling an electric scooter. I accidentally managed to pull out all the wires so they looked as in picture 1.

[image: picture 1]

I wrote to the company who advised me to solder it as shown in picture 2

[image: picture 2]

But after a few tries, one of which led to some smoke and burning I am now left with picture 3.

[image: Picture 3]

As you can see, I managed to pull out a solder pad altogether (which led to the blue wire). On reading some other posts around this, I asked the company if the connection was used at all or was just a dummy. But any advice on what I could do to salvage this? The other side of the circuit is the LED panel itself and I haven't so I don't have a way to get to the other side of the pad. It seems wasteful to me to throwaway the entire scooter just because a few wires were loose but on the other hand I'm not very good at this and with the experience where there was smoke, I'm a bit scared as well since the scooter is used by my son. It all connects down to a 4000 mAh, 25 V lithium ion battery.

Later, the company responded saying that the blue wire has no role and is a dummy. Would it be enough then to just solder the other 5 wires back into place?
I'm wondering also what could have caused the smoke and burning and what might I have done wrong which I avoid in the next try?

Comment: Devu - Hi, (a) re: "*company responded [...] blue wire has no role*" That could be wrong, as the [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/553041/101852) from *Spehro* clearly shows a damaged PCB trace leading from where you soldered the blue wire, towards the area of the SOT-23 device N1. (b) Re: "*what could have caused the smoke*" That same answer has highlighted that you now have *at least* one damaged component. You have no schematic, and we can't go back in time to see all the steps you performed, so we can't see how the damage was caused. Likely needs *local* troubleshooting now.

Comment: I wrote back again to the company and obtained a link to buy a new panel altogether. Given that I clearly lack the skills and experience to execute this job and because it's quite expensive to take it to a repair shop where I live (Sweden), I have grudgingly ordered a new scooter. 
That said, I have the old scooter lying around and I find myself eager to order the part and some better tools (precision solder) and try this again. I just might with someone watching over me. Thanks everyone for helping and @Spehro you truly have an amazing eye.

Comment: For the record, before you tried to repair this yourself, I'd forget about the repair shop (they can't solder, just replace boards) and go find a local electronics assembly company. Then buy them a nice big cake. I bet most would take that deal :) And then you would have gotten a solder job done by a pro. A cake is quite a bit cheaper than a new scooter :)

Answer (score 5):

You may be better off ordering a new board. You seem to have shorted something and destroyed at least one part (D5). There may be more hidden damage.

At least one trace has also been peeled back, it used to go to the  drain on MOSFET N1. It does not appear to have gone to the back of the board (there would have to be a hole for that).

Repairs on something like this are possible for someone with full information, fine soldering skills and reasonably decent tools, but without those things may possibly cause additional issues.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you'll  need a new board, Spehro has a good eye.

if the $0.25 diode wasn't burnt out ,  ...

- use some hard polyurethane adhesive to secure all the wires like sub-floor adhesive in tubes from H/W store, (maybe epoxy but it flows too much)

1st solder the 5 wires to look exactly like photo.
2nd  bond the 6th wire to the fifth with only enough wire exposed to solder AWG 24 jumper wire from the rugged wire tip to all the points that are connected to traces from this pad.

They were broken from poor workmanship not (to) have this strain relief.

Use 10x eye piece or macro camera to examine all the traces leading to this pad (1 or 2)?
Then use crazy glue to bond the jumper wire or preferably AWG30 magnet wire.  You can solder and burn thru the insulation quickly and tin the ends < 5s.

Comment: Note thats with new magnet wire.  With older magnet wire you have to use an acid bath or sandpaper to remove the insulation.  May I never buy a spool of the older stuff again.

Comment: @KH I have a 5lb spool of AWG30 wire (bought at Active Surplus on Queen St., Tony would know them) made Nov 26, 1966 in Port Huron MI and it solders through nicely. 15,312 feet originally. Definitely a lifetime supply for me unless I start mass producing Tesla coils or something.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm envious.  I have not nearly that much left from a large roll my dad got.  I don't think it's even as old as yours but I've wound a motor core with it and it's very frustrating to work with as I don't have an acid bath and even using a torch before sandpaper only chars and weakens it.  Had to sand down 16 tiny leads without scratching the windings.  I've actually had anxiety over purchasing more wire because I don't want that type again and I'm worried about picking a budget supplier lol.

Comment: @KH Hot caustic works well with Formvar, Kapton and other high temperature and cryogenic/vacuum compatible enamels, but it's not for the faint of heart.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks good to know what to avoid.  My wire may very well be one of those types